# Transactions doesnt work in junit?

Tags: spring, junit, transactions

There is quite a few questions here about Transactions and JUnit. But please have a read through this before discarding it as i cant find anyone with the same issues.

I have a buisness method, annotated `@Transactional`. Within this method i will be doing a programaticly rollback if some special condition occurs. `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();`

Now lets not get into a discussion about if a programaticly rollback is good or bad. Lets just accept its there, and accept its going to stay there and work with it.

If I fire up my application and test this buisness method the old fashioned way, then everything works perfectly. When stuff is supposed to be rolled back, it is rolled back and when everything is ok, then everything is ok. And I also did a test without the `@Transactional` just to see that nothing gets rolled back, even when it should. 
Everything works as planned.

But the issues im having is with JUnit. Currently I have 2 JUnit tests of this method. 1 that should fail (and trigger a programaticly rollback) and one that is successfull without rollback.

I have tried a lot of different setups of my Junit class. Currently it looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:springTestContext.xml", "classpath:springTestContext-dao.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager")
public class MyManagerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Mock
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @InjectMocks
    MyManager myManager = new MyManagerImpl();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnParsableXml() {
        String xml = "adlsfas";
        Response response = myManager.processXMLContent(xml);
        assertFalse(response.isSuccess());
        System.out.println(response.getResponse());
    }

}
@Service("myManager")
public class MyManagerImpl extends BaseManager implements MyManager {
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Response processXMLContent(String xml) {
       /* NB. Extremly simplified version.... */
       Response response = new Response();
       try {
            parseXml(); // just dummy sample. Its actually parsing xml
            response.setSuccess(true)
       catch(SAXException e) {
           TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
           response.setSuccess(false);
       }
       return response;
    }
}
```

The springTestContext has the `<tx:annotation-driven` annotation, and the dao-context has a transactionmanager, entityfactory and a datasource.
Probably shouldnt even need those? As this test has absolutly nothing to do in the db. All I want to test is that a programaticly rollback is done in the transaction if it fails.

But the reason to why I added them was because of the error im trying to get help with here. Whenever a programaticly rollback is called in the buisness-method, then I always get this error (only for junit tests, works perfectly otherwise):

```
org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
```

So my question to you is: What am i doing wrong. How can i get my buisness method to have a transaction?
And then as a bonus question, how can i test that a rollback was called on the transaction?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Can you try adding `@Transactional` above `MyManagerTest` class? Also you are aware that Spring test transactions try to be smarter and are always automatically rolled back after each test?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and I have also tried to set @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false), but in both cases = same exception... :(

Comment: Could it be that springs transaction tests are so "smart" that its not really a transaction that is being passed to the method? And then when the method tries to do a programaticly rollback, it fails because its not really a transaction there. Its just some sort of dummy-transaction used by spring?

Comment: How do you access this @Transactional annotated method? Do you inject the bean into the unit test and access the method using the bean?
Please add the code where the method gets called.

Comment: I just updated the question with the code where the method gets called. As you can see the Bean is instatiated in the test-class itself. All dependecies are mocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You creating a new instance of MyManager class `MyManager myManager = new MyManagerImpl();` instead of using the actual bean from the context

```
@Resource(name="myContext")
MyManager myManager;
```

Obviously, [no proxy is being created](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/) and the MyManager instance you are referring to is not even a Spring bean, because it's not created inside the DI container.

As for `@Transactional` annotated methods in the test classes, I believe they are executed with [TransactionalTestExecutionListener](http://srcrr.com/java/spring/3.1.0/reference/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html)(so the mechanism is a bit different than in the container), but I think that should not affect the transaction wrappers in the container itself - see beforeTestMethod and afterTestMethod to check what is done with the PlatformTransactionManager if it's needed.

From the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management):

> In the TestContext framework, transactions are managed by the
>   TransactionalTestExecutionListener, which is configured through the
>   @TestExecutionListeners annotation by default, even if you do not
>   explicitly declare @TestExecutionListeners on your test class. To
>   enable support for transactions, however, you must provide a
>   PlatformTransactionManager bean in the application context loaded by
>   @ContextConfiguration semantics. In addition, you must declare
>   @Transactional either at the class or method level.

So I think that there's not so much difference between running `@Transactional` annotated methods of the test clases and of the actual beans(with the exception of the default rollback flag on the test classes of course) - both  TransactionAspectSupport and TransactionalTestExecutionListener just call the methods of the underlying [PlatformTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html).

P.S. as for your integration test, it's not clear what you are trying to mock the beans(both ProductDao and MyManager) - when we do integration testing with Spring, we test how the real beans interact together, mocking only the dependencies external to the container(for example using MockServletContext instead of the binding to the real web server) or replacing the dependencies on the heavyweight/production level servers with the lightweight/embedded ones - that is the balance between the realistic conditions, the convenience and the test execution speed.

Comment: Thanks for your long and descriptive answer. It looks like this is the correct solution, however I have not been able to test it. The combination of mocks and spring-context is catching me and is painful to work through. Why im trying to mock ProductDao? Well its because productDao is a dependency of which MyManager needs. (Its not clear from the codesample since its deleted for space-purposes..). And this is not an integration test, it is a unit test, and thats why i need to mock productdao. I definatly do not want the actual dao-object to be used.

Comment: You should declare @autowired property in your MyManagerImlpl, that is what Spring container is designed for :) `@Autowired  public setProductDao(ProductDao  productDao){this.productDao = productDao; } ` - if MyManagerImpl and ProductDao are instantiated in the same Spring container,  Spring will resolve the dependency and set the respective property. Just to be clear - you don't need to mock anything here at all if you are not quite sure in otherwise - mocks have not much to do with the *integration* testing - they are designed mostly for the *unit* testing which is done without Spring DI.

Comment: That is how DI is a kind of Inversion of Control - you delegate the the creation of your objects to container(lose some control) - and container resolves the dependencies for you, so you don't have to set the values of fields from inside the class - http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: When designing classes according to Dependency Injection principle we declare the class dependencies(which in old times would be created as private fields initialized inside the class) as constructor arguments and public setters, so it's not the class who resolve the dependency but the external code that creates the object. So if the Spring creates the object it will be able to resolve the dependencies(provide the constructor arguments and set the respective field values) only using its configuration.

Comment: For `@transactional` to work, the class using your service must use it as a bean provided with Spring(you can tell spring to inject it for example with `@Resource` annotation) - spring will create a proxy object(that will call begin/commit/rollback on PlatformTransactionManager when someone invokes the proxie's `processXMLContent()`) and set field to the reference to that proxy object. Of course, for `@Resource` anonnotation to work Spring must somehow be aware of the object(for example the object can be created with Spring), in this case bean wiring works because of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Comment: @user829237 you can ask further questions I understand that it's a bit too much of information :-)

Comment: Thanks Boris! I understand how Autowiring works. The thing is only this: I want a mock of productDao. ProductDao is Autowired within MyManager. And productDao is not defined in the my unit-test-context.xml. So thats why im doing `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` on MyManager. Because I want to mock productDao, but I'd like not to mock it by xml-declaration, i'd like to mock it from within the junit-code. But unfortunalty im not able to make this work yet.. So i guess i'll switch to xml-mocking if i cant get any closer. But loads of thanks for all help so far.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to set ProductDao reference in Spring, but what you're doing is seems to be more like a *unit* test of MyManager, not *integration* test. When we unit test the beans, we test the classes in isolation and do not use neither Spring nor Test Context frameworks at all - we provide the references to the mocks manually with public setters and constructor arguments. Nevertheless you can declare a custom ProductDao implementation in test specific configuration and use factory method to invoke the mocking framework, but it's unlikely how should it to be done.

Comment: The simplest thing is to return the bean instance with "@bean" annotated method in the configuration , I suppose.

Comment: Yes exactly. Im doing a unit test, thats why im mocking. And thats why i dont want a test-context at all. And thats the original reason for this question. How can I unit test this transactional method without all the contexts. All I actually need to test is that a call to rollback the transaction is made. Would be easy if i could just mock the transaction...

Comment: I think that you can mock PlatformTransactionManager instance but it needs some reading, I'm not at the PC right now :-)

Comment: @user829237, actually there is not much you can do with `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()` in a pure unit test because the methods that actually bind the transaction to the current thread are coupled to the method invocation logic in TransactionAspectSupport. But you can explicitly use PlatformTransactionManager instead, its instance can be easily mocked.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run the test with the **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner** which is set by the **AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests**, however you have overridden it with the **MockitoJunitRunner**.  Simply remove the **RunWith** at the top of your test and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried this. Look at my modified code. Unfortunatly I still get the exact same error... :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass this test，you can add  @Test(expected = NoTransactionException.class) on your method.

Comment: `@Test(expected = NoTransactionException.class)
    public void testUnParsableXml() {
        String xml = "adlsfas";
        Response response = myManager.processXMLContent(xml);
        assertFalse(response.isSuccess());
        System.out.println(response.getResponse());
    }`

Comment: This attribute is not present in JUnit5.